# Hiding checklisted cell in excel

Tags: excel

I'm making a to do list. I have an original checklist with all the items but want a separate table with ones ticked yes and no. I tried an if true statement but don't know how to make all the cells appear.   I want it to add a ticked item to the column array.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer, but it's a first lead to a solution: using the checkbox's format, you can put the value of the checkbox (being `TRUE` or `false`) in another cell. Then, you can look for the values `TRUE` or `FALSE` in the corresponding columns.

Example screenshot:

[image]